# Asterisks in Fortran: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

Tags: fortran, asterisk, subroutine, fortran77

In the following fortran77 code, there is this subroutine definition

```
  SUBROUTINE MSIRNS ( D , NOBST , N , X , R , RR , SURFT ,
 ,                    INOBSI , ISUR , IDELTS , IRELPS ,
 ,                    RNOBSI , RSUR , RDELTS , RRELPS ,
 ,                    OBSD , * , * )
```

what is the meaning of the two last arguments, asterisks?

and how can I therefore call the function?

I tried all these variants

```
RES = CALL MSIRNS (D, NOBST, N, X, R, RR, SURFT, INOBSI, ISUR, IDELTS, IRELPS, RNOBSI, RSUR, RDELTS, RRELPS, OBSD, *, *)
    CALL MSIRNS (D, NOBST, N, X, R, RR, SURFT, INOBSI, ISUR, IDELTS, IRELPS, RNOBSI, RSUR, RDELTS, RRELPS, OBSD, *, *)
    RES = CALL MSIRNS (D, NOBST, N, X, R, RR, SURFT, INOBSI, ISUR, IDELTS, IRELPS, RNOBSI, RSUR, RDELTS, RRELPS, OBSD)
```

but always get

> Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an alternate return specifier:

http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-15.html#sh-15.8.3

In the code that calls MSIRNS(), you need to replace the asterisks with "*N", where N is the label of the alternate return line.

Comment: Definitely old code ... alternate return was declared to be "obsolescence" in Fortran 95 and should not be used in new programs.